# I test ran my shiny app and it worked. However, it gives me an error when I uploaded it to shinyapp.io and ran it

Tags: r, shiny

I ran my shiny app on shinyapp.io server and it gave me this error:

"ERROR: object of type 'closure' is not subsettable"

I have following server.R and UI.R files:

SERVER.R

```
library(shiny)
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

data <- data.table::fread(input="final_master_table.csv",header = TRUE,     data.table = TRUE)
data <- data[,V1:=NULL]

shinyServer(function(input, output){

selected_data <- reactive({

minyear <- input$year[1]
maxyear <- input$year[2]

velo <- data %>% group_by(pitcher_name, pitch_type, Year) %>% summarise(velocity = mean(start_speed)) %>%
  arrange(velocity) %>% filter(pitcher_name %in% input$pitcher_name) %>% arrange(pitcher_name) %>% filter(Year >= minyear) %>% filter(Year <= maxyear) %>% filter(pitch_type %in% input$pitch_type)
print(velo)
 })

output$pitcher_bar <- renderPlot({

p <- ggplot(data=selected_data(), aes(x = Year, y = velocity, group = pitch_type, color = pitch_type)) + geom_line() + geom_point(size=3, fill="white") + xlab("Year") + ylab("Velocity") + ggtitle("Velocity") + theme_bw()
print(p)
})


})
```

UI.R

```
 library(shiny)
 library(data.table)
 library(dplyr)
 library(ggplot2)

shinyUI(fluidPage(

titlePanel("Velocity Attribute"),

sidebarLayout(

sidebarPanel(

# Slider for setting year parameter

sliderInput("year",
            "year:",
            min=2008,max=2015,value=c(2008,2015)
            ),

selectInput("pitcher_name","Pitcher Name:", choices = unique(data$pitcher_name)),

selectInput("pitch_type","Pitch Type:", choices = unique(data$pitch_type)),

helpText("Please wait 30 seconds for 2008 to 2015 pitchFx data to load")

),

mainPanel(plotOutput("pitcher_bar"))

)))
```

I am suspecting that the adjustments need to be made has to do with data variable?

Comment: Did you upload the csv file to the server as well? Is that the only error you get?

Comment: I think it's looking for "final_master_table.csv", which is in your local working directory but not on the server.

Comment: I will figure out if I have more errors once this is resolved. (Other error messages tend to surface only when one error is fixed)

Comment: I am downloading the bundle off my account. Bundle file is big, which suggest that csv file was uploaded to server earlier. csv file is 1GB big.

Comment: csv file was uploaded in the server, I just checked. Maybe since csv file is on server, I have to specify urlpath? (Server.R script indicating 'data' variable is filepath to my work directory.) I don't know how to specify the urlpath of the csv file.. Does anyone know how to find it?